# Update Post Meta for a logged in user

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field, post-meta

I have created a form which collects information which I want to update a post with. The code I have works great, but instead of updating a post for the user, it creates a new one. Not sure what I am missing to get the current post to update instead of creating a new post. Here is the code I am using:

```
function update_role_and_post($record,$ajax_handler)
{
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings('form_name');
    if ('Confirm Premium Account' !== $form_name) {
        return;
    }
    
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$current_user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
$current_user->add_role( 'editor' );
    $form_data = $record->get_formatted_data();
    $update=$form_data["Content"]; 
    
    
    
// EVERYTHING UP TO THIS POINT WORKS
// EVERYTHING BELOW DOES NOT WORK!
    
    
// Assign the ID from the current WP_User object to a var for use below
$user_id = $current_user->ID;

    
$confirm=array( 
    'subscription'=> $subscription  // Wanting to use what is in the form and place it as the value for the upgraded meta-key
);
    
    
// Create array of arguments for our query
$args = array(
    'author' => $user_id,  // defined above
    'post_status' => 'publish',  // ignore deleted/drafted posts
    'fields' => 'ids',  // we only need the IDs
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_input'      => $confirm
);

// Query for posts by this author
$author_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

// WP_Query object contains lots of info; we only want the posts which will be an array if IDs based on our fields argument above.
$author_post_ids = $author_posts->posts;  // array of IDs only

// Loop through each post by this author
foreach ( $author_post_ids as $post_id ) {
    // On each loop iteration, update the post meta keys here
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
} 
}
```

Comment: Did you come up with a different solution for this question?

Comment: Not yet. the things I have tried based on your response and things I have tried always result in a new post. I have not been able to figure out what the issue is yet. From what I see and understand, everything should work, but doesn't

Comment: If you update your question with your current code I will take a look.  In my test site, the below code updates the existing post w/o creating a new post.  I would suspect an issue with the ID being passing as that will trigger creation of a new post IIRC.

Comment: Code has been updated.

Comment: OK I see a few problems to fix. I can update the answer below with those changes.  Question: your meta field key is `subscription` but what value are you trying to write to that meta field?  With that answer I can update below.

Comment: I am trying to change the post meta value from "free" to "premium". This actual meta value will not be displayed anywhere, but other data on the web page will either display or be hidden based on this meta value.

Comment: Updated below to include your meta key and meta value.  I simplified some and put it all together in your `update_role_and_post` function.  See the bottom of the answer after the final EDIT.  The `$ajax_handler` in your function declaration was not used so I removed that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to WPSE.

A few problems to note:

1. $user_id is not defined so your call to wp_get_current_user() is passing a null value as a parameter.

`$current_user = wp_get_current_user($user_id);. // $user_id is not defined`

2. `wp_get_current_user()` does not accept parameters. See the documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/
3. This line `$current_user->ID;` does nothing. There is no ID method in the WP_User class.

You can simplify that section as follow:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$current_user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
$current_user->add_role( 'editor' );

// Assign the ID from the current WP_User object to a var for use below
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

Regarding post update vs creation, `wp_update_post()` expects an ID for the post you are updating.  You appear to pass the user ID as `$my_post['import_id']` which is not valid.

Are you attempting to update the user object or a post with user information?

**EDIT: OP wishes to update the meta key/value of each post for the current author.**

The code above solves the user role challenge and the following is a model for updating the post meta for each post that specific user has authored.

Note: `update_post_meta()` needs the post ID, the meta_key (the slug for the field) and the meta_value for each field you are updating.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/

```
// Create array of arguments for our query
$args = array(
    'author' => $user_id,  // defined above
    'post_status' => 'publish',  // ignore deleted/drafted posts
    'fields' => 'ids'  // we only need the IDs
);

// Query for posts by this author
$author_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

// WP_Query object contains lots of info; we only want the posts which will be an array if IDs based on our fields argument above.
$author_post_ids = $author_posts->posts;  // array of IDs only

// Loop through each post by this author
foreach ( $author_post_ids as $post_id ) {
    // On each loop iteration, update the post meta keys here
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
}
```

**EDIT** adding actual meta key and value specifics for OP.

```
function update_role_and_post( $record ) {

    if ( 'Confirm Premium Account' !== $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Update current user role to editor
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    $current_user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
    $current_user->add_role( 'editor' );
    
    // Create array of arguments for our query
    $args = array(
        'author' => $current_user->ID, 
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'fields' => 'ids' 
    );
    
    // Query for posts by this author
    $author_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    // Parse the post IDs from the rest of the WP_Query object
    $author_post_ids = $author_posts->posts;
    
    // Loop through each post by this author and update to premium
    foreach ( $author_post_ids as $post_id ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'subscription', 'premium' );
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I am confused on how to get the post ID for a user's posts. What I am trying to achieve is to update a specific post meta value with the value from the form for all posts with the logged in user when they click submit on the form. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: You can query posts by author ID, build an array of those post IDs, then iterate through that array, updating the specific meta field on each post.  If that is your goal, I can update the answer with one approach to that.

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Updated to include a sample of how to update the meta fields for each post for the current author.

Comment: Thanks jdm2112, but the code you provide still creates an entirely new post. The user meta is updated correctly and the post itself contains the correct meta, but the meta is in a new post instead of the author's existing post. Not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: This code works as expected on my sandbox site.  Can you add the code you are using as an edit to your original question?

Comment: You are the man!! This worked great! I found out that I created redundant code which looks to have trumped this code and make it look like things were not working. After removing that redundant code, all works great!! Thank you greatly!!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Happy to help!